# Difference between a base class and a contitioned generic

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I noticed after some time using generics that there was not much difference between this:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T t) where T : BaseClass{

}
```

and this:

```
public void DoSomething(BaseClass t){

}
```

The only difference I have seen so far is that the first method could be added other constraints, like interfaces or `new ()`, but if you use it just the way that I wrote it, I don´t see much difference. Can anybody point any important factors about choosing one or another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think most visible difference is type of the parameter inside method will be different - in generic case actual type, non-generic - always `BaseClass`.

This information is useful when you need to call other generic classes/methods.

```
 class Cat : Animal {}

 void DoSomething<T>(T animal) where T:Animal
 {
    IEnumerable<T> repeatGeneric = Enumerable.Repeat(animal, 3);
    var repeatGenericVar = Enumerable.Repeat(animal, 3);
 } 
 void DoSomething(Animal animal)
 {
    IEnumerable<Animal> repeat = Enumerable.Repeat(animal, 3);
    var repeatVar = Enumerable.Repeat(animal, 3);
 }
```

Now if you call both with `new Cat()`:

- type of both `repeatGeneric` and `repeatGenericVar` will be `IEnumerable<Cat>`  (note that `var` statically finds the type, shown to highlight the fact type is known statically)
- type of both `repeat` and `repeatVar` will be `IEnumrable<Animal>` despite the fact that `Cat` was passed in.

Comment: For your answer I am thinking that it is generally a better idea to use the generic version, so you are able to keep more information on the type.

Comment: @Gerard - I would not say one is better - they serve different purposes and have different drawbacks. I.e. generics and inheritance often cause confusion: with `class My<T>{}` following types `My<int>` and `My<string>` feel related in some way but they are just 2 separate types; proper testing of generic methods require more cases due to openness: `void Do(int)` needs test for some `int` values, but `Void Do<T>(T)` need test for some value types, reference types; mixing generic and non-generic code sometimes hard especially when generic needs real type...